# Symfony 6 php 8 Entity Form

Tags: php, class, symfony

I'm trying to create a form with Symfony 6 (without database behind).

I create an Entity like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

class MyObject
{
    private string $name;

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    public function setName($name): self
    {
        $this->$name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}

?>
```

I created the MyObjectFormType with `symfony console make:entity` command.

After that when I tried to show the form into my twig page, I've got an error `Warning: Undefined variable $name`.
I saw that in older version of php (and symfony) this annotation was used:

```
/**
 * @Var
 */
```

Does it exist on php 8 (by attributes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error, it's not:

```
$this->$name
```

but:

```
$this->name
```